# Is there a way to switch voice genders for AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?

Tags: ios, cocoa, text-to-speech

I'm building simple text to speech app and curious if it's possible to switch between genders of the voice?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your [`AVSpeechUtterance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechUtterance_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVSpeechUtterance)'s `voice` property to one of the [currently available voices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesisVoice_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/AVSpeechSynthesisVoice/voiceWithLanguage:). Available voices change based on system and locale. You can also adjust the utterance's `pitchMultiplier`, `volume`, `rate`, and delay properties to further adjust the sound.

Comment: I have set pitchMultiplier but it is not proper gender voice. Is this possible to change gender voice ?